# How to fix a bug in the Alarm Manager?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to make a function in my application to send a notification every 5 seconds:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       final AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       final Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ShowFormula.class);
       final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
       buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view){
                am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
                Log.i(TAG, "started");
            }
        });
```

and this is receiver code:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceive working");
        if (b) {
            Log.i(TAG, "notification started");
            makeNotification(context);
        }
    public void makeNotification(Context context){
        Log.i(TAG, "notification continued");
        <...notification code...>
    }
```

and this is logs:

```
2020-08-04 18:23:34.451 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: started
2020-08-04 18:24:02.074 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: onReceive working
2020-08-04 18:24:02.077 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification started
2020-08-04 18:24:02.077 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification continued
2020-08-04 18:24:34.455 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: onReceive working
2020-08-04 18:24:34.456 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification started
2020-08-04 18:24:34.456 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification continued
2020-08-04 18:25:57.792 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: onReceive working
2020-08-04 18:25:57.793 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification started
2020-08-04 18:25:57.793 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification continued
2020-08-04 18:26:57.804 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: onReceive working
2020-08-04 18:26:57.805 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification started
2020-08-04 18:26:57.805 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification continued
2020-08-04 18:28:02.358 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: onReceive working
2020-08-04 18:28:02.359 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification started
2020-08-04 18:28:02.359 5492-5492/com.example.learner I/MyApp: notification continued
```

As you see, **onReceive()** called wit random intervals. where can there be a problem? Help me please!

Comment: Not sure what the requirements are, but if you merely want a timer in your foreground Activity then AlarmManager is not a good choice. For that, you might want to consider a Handler or CountDownTimer or other options. But with regards to AlarmManager, it is not technically possible to run it every 5 seconds. Regards.

Comment: No, I need to show notification even if the activity closed. So, what is the minimum time for alarm manager? at first I created a new alarm manager every time the onReceive() was called. it worked 2-4 times, but after that it started the same as now.

Comment: It is a little complicated to explain...But what you are trying to do has not been possible since Android 6 when Doze was introduced. Prior to that, I believe AlarmManager alarms were constrained to run a max of once per minute. See these docs: [Schedule repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms). Pay special attention to the bits that describe doze. But in summary, when the device is not charging and the user turns the screen OFF, alarms have to wait for a maintenance window to fire.

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

with

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 5000, pendingIntent);
```

`setRepeating` is more accurate

Comment: Since api level 19 `setRepeating` is functionally deprecated and behaves like `setInexactRepeating`. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)